# Make sure Oracle insert statement in order

Tags: oracle, insert

I have an ArrayList let's say with 4 rows in defined order. I want to insert these 4 rows into Oracle table accordingly. But weird, it gets into the table but with wrong order.

```
for (int x = 0; x < myArray.size(); x++) {
   //Some validation
   //insert statement
   MyJB myJB = (MyJB) myArray.get(x);
   String query = "insert into table X values(myJB.getColumn1,myJB.getColumn2)";
   log.debug(query);
   stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   stmt.executeUpdate();
   stmt.close();
}
```

The log will show the correct order, i.e from x=0 to x=3.
But select * from table X will result 4 rows but with different order

How to force Oracle will insert in correct order as in ArrayList?

Thanks

- ArrayList = row0,row1,row2,row3
- select * from Table X = row2,row3,row0,row1

Comment: What order are you talking about?  Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of results of a `SELECT` statement is in-determinant-- rows can be returned in an arbitrary order and the order can change on every execution.  If you care about the order rows are returned from a `SELECT` statement, use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: It's the order of the ArrayList. The data is from ArrayList not table so I cannot do "order by".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you define sort order, you cannot rely on order of elements. The best way is to create primary key from sequence and order by it.

Alternatively you may try oracle specific rownum pseudocolumn:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm
but IMHO it is not what you want.

EDIT

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySequence;

PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table XY values (mySequence.nextval, ?, ?)");
statement.setObject(1, myJB.getColumn1);
statement.setObject(2, myJB.getColumn2);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

And then

```
select * from XY order by Z asc
```

where Z is name of first column will do what you want

Comment: The order is already defined as in ArrayList. That is the correct order. Insert statement has processed it one by one in correct order. But the select result is in wrong order even if select * from table X order by rowid desc

Comment: @JustinCave explained it nicely. It does not matter how you store the values, but how you retrieve them. And for that you must define sort order criteria. You cannot rely on order of inserting rows.

Comment: hmm that's a good point. But users see on that ArrayList (this comes from a data file). Any trick to force Oracle show the data as in order we insert the data?

Comment: yes, add new column and initialize it from sequence. I will update my answear.

Comment: add new column in table or as in ArrayList? How to make this column as sequence?

Comment: new column in table, see example. I do not DDL of your table, so I cannot update it. But I hope that it is clear now. You need sequence and new column in your table. When you insert data then add next value from the sequence to this new column.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I got this clear. But will this sequence guarantee the order of inserting rows? I mean in the loop of ArrayList, will it execute one by one in order? Wouldn't it be the same as rowid or rownum? As you said earlier we cannot rely on order of inserting rows but how to retrieve them.

Comment: Sequence.nextval is guaranteed to return the value just once. Of course if other thread will insert data at the same time, then data from both parallel threads will be mixed together - to avoid it you need to lock your table.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. So sequence.nectval has different than rowid/rownum right?

Comment: Sequence is number holder, you define its start value and increment value. Each call to nextval will return next value and store it regardless of transactions. You can get the current value with currval as many times as you want.